# primefaces ternary column width

Tags: css, primefaces, datatable, width

I'm trying to have the column width to vary based on the value being null or not.

```
<:column                                            attribName=     "name" 
                                                    width=          "#{(_item.value eq null)? (260) : (50)}"
                                                    value=          "#{_item.value}" 
                                                    headerTxt=      "value"
                                                    visibleColumn=  "true"
                                                    writableCol=    "false"/>
```

The sizing works fine when the value is null, but it stops as soon as it changes.
I also tried to use styleClass with some css instead of width but without luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where does `_item.value` come from? The var attribute on the `p:datatable`?

Comment: The item comes from the bean. What do I need the var attribute for?